# R negative subscripts

Tags: r

I am trying to get shifts of my array, so I've written a really simply function as follows:

```
getLagMatrix <- function(df, k){

    output <- df$AAPL[ k : nrow(df) ]
    for( i in c(1 : k) ){

            toPaste <- paste('_',i, sep='')

            print( c(i, nrow(df) - k + i - 1 ) )
            toBind <- df [ c(i : nrow(df) - k + i - 1), ] #the problem is obviously here
            names(toBind) <- paste(names(toBind),toPaste,sep='') 
            output <- cbind( output, toBind )
    }
}
```

Then I call:

```
> dim(returns)
[1] 3103    6   
> getLagMatrix(returns, 3)
```

And then it prints:

```
[1]    1 3100
Error in xj[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I have no idea why this is causing me such a problem, but its probably something obvious I'm not seeing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a small sample input and desired output?

Comment: `:` has higher precedence. Order of ops.

Comment: To expand on joran's note, take a look at the difference between `1:10-1` and `1:(10-1)`

Comment: Embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: @jaslibra - far from embarrassing. There have been plenty of experienced users caught out by precedence of operation issues.